# Python BeautifulSoup duvidas

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Estou fazendo um requests.post e ele me retorna as seguintes informações:

```
{"Name":"Joey Triibianni","Vocation":"Knight","Level":"425","World":"Quelibra","Account Status:":"Free Account"}
```

Já tentei de algumas formas porém não estou conseguindo fazer a formatação por blocos. Eu queria apenas os valores World : {value}, Account Status: {value}.

Comment: Isso parece ser um JSON. Conhece esse formato?

Comment: muito pouco, sou iniciante em python.

Comment: JSON é um formato de texto estruturado, independente do Python. Sugiro que pesquise o básico sobre ele antes de continuar.

Comment: passei dessa forma p/ obter aquela resposta.

Comment: Obrigado Anderson, o JSON foi a resposta mesmo.. consegui resolver.

Comment: Aliás, se está utilizando o Requests, o BeatifulSoup é desnecessário.

Comment: Está ok, obrigado pelas dicas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A URL que está requisitando retorna um JSON. A biblioteca BeatifulSoup serve para analisar documentos XML (e, por consequência, HTML). Ou seja, não precisa utilizá-la.

A própria biblioteca Requests já faz tudo o que precisa:

```
import requests

response = requests.post(url, data)

if response.ok:
    json = response.json()
    world = json['World']
    status = json['Account Status']
```